# Is it possible to get the Start date and the end date of a survey from SurveyMonkey API

Tags: surveymonkey

Does the API return information on when the respondent took the survey and when they completed it? I see that the start and end date-time details are available in the website when I download the results from the Analyze Results Tab. I don't see this information in any of the API methods, am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the end-date is associated to the collector, not to the survey. However it seems there is no way to get it even with get_collector_list API

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_list

data.surveys[_].date_created
(Optional)  Date survey was created Date String

data.surveys[_].date_modified
(Optional)  Date survey was last modified   Date String